# Change defaults for Fullcalendar themeSystem

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Currently using Bootstrap 4 with the new integration for Fullcalendar.io. It's working amazingly, but I've been trying to figure out how to change the defaults for the button classes as defined in Line 14 of https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/theme/Bootstrap4Theme.ts:

```
export default class Bootstrap4Theme extends Theme {
}

Bootstrap4Theme.prototype.classes = {
  widget: 'fc-bootstrap4',

  tableGrid: 'table-bordered', // avoid `table` class b/c don't want margins. only border color
  tableList: 'table', // `table` class creates bottom margin but who cares
  tableListHeading: 'table-active',

  buttonGroup: 'btn-group',
  button: 'btn btn-primary',
  stateActive: 'active',
  stateDisabled: 'disabled',

  today: 'alert alert-info', // the plain `info` class requires `.table`, too much to ask
  popover: 'card card-primary',
  popoverHeader: 'card-header',
  popoverContent: 'card-body',

  // day grid
  // for left/right border color when border is inset from edges (all-day in agenda view)
  // avoid `table` class b/c don't want margins/padding/structure. only border color.
  headerRow: 'table-bordered',
  dayRow: 'table-bordered',

  // list view
  listView: 'card card-primary'
}
```

I'd like to modify the default of **.btn-primary** to be **.btn-outline-secondary**.

Is there any way I can do this by modifying the defaults for the Bootstrap 4 theme on Fullcalendar?

Comment: you can either change the source code to use different classes, or override the CSS definitions for those classes so they look different. There's no option via the API, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping since they're defined that way there would be an easy way to overwrite those properties. 

I'd really like to avoid changing the source so that I can stay up-to-date with future releases without too much headache.

Comment: I agree, but there isn't any such thing at the moment as far as I know. Perhaps you could submit a feature request to the people who maintain fullCalendar (see the "Contribute" section of the website). Alternatively you could fork the theme and customise it to your liking. It does mean you have an increase in maintenance overhead though. Maybe since you only want to make a small change, overriding the CSS rules for those classes would be simpler.